# Swift @IBDesignable/@IBInspectable UIView styling

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uiview

I'm trying to style my `UIView` inside table cell prototype to have it shadow for it and a couple more styling customization but for some reason when I build the project the changes are not applied.

I have the next code for it in separate file `CustomView.swift`

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class CustomView: UIView {



    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
            layer.masksToBounds = cornerRadius > 0
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var shadowOpacity: Float = 0 {
        didSet {
            layer.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var shadowRadius: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            layer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var shadowOffset: CGSize = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.0) {
        didSet {
            layer.shadowOffset = shadowOffset
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var shadowColor: UIColor? = UIColor(red: 157/255, green: 157/255, blue: 157/255, alpha: 1.0) {
        didSet {
            layer.shadowColor = shadowColor?.cgColor
        }
    }

}
```

I see the field inside the "Attribute inspector" of Xcode 9
[image: "Attribute inspector" of Xcode 9]

but after building it the change are not applied basically I don't see the shadow for view.

The most interesting that I'm using the same approach to customize text fields as well as buttons and this code works for `UIButton/UITextField` but not for `UIView`

Does someone know why it doesn't work for `UIView` ?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check your code:

```
layer.masksToBounds = cornerRadius > 0
```

Change that to:

```
layer.masksToBounds = false
```

And also make sure that your `clipsToBounds` is set to `false` either in code like so:

```
clipsToBounds = false
```

or in your storyboard like so:

[image]

Comment: hi, thank you for coming back to me. I tried your code suggestion and it did not work out for me. That is how my story board looks like this [storyboard](https://i.imgur.com/xcRwYbu.png) and after building the project that is what I see in simulator for IPhone8 [sim_result](https://i.imgur.com/t0XtB7p.png) no shadow. The code in my CustomView.swift the same plus your suggested change.

Comment: in your storyboard screenshot I can't see the clipsToBounds flag, check if that's not set to true, that should be false also

Comment: Hi yeah, I think that was a problem after setting clipToBounds to false it started to work. I really appreciate your help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please Update the function

```
@IBInspectable
    var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for response, I tried your code suggestion and it did not work out for me. That is how my story board looks like this [storyboard](https://i.imgur.com/xcRwYbu.png) and after building the project that is what I see in simulator for IPhone8 [sim_result](https://i.imgur.com/t0XtB7p.png) no shadow. The code in my CustomView.swift the same plus your suggested change.